# How can I run a list of commands in parallel?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, system, systems-programming

I have a file containing command lines that I want to run. This file contains around 2,000 lines.

I have 8 cores available. Is it possible to parse the file and start 8 processes, then execute another one from the file whenever one of the programs finishes? I want this to continue until the end of file is reached.

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use *xargs* to read in the file, while limiting the maximum number of processes to the number of available cores. For example:

```
cores=$(fgrep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)
xargs --arg-file=/tmp/foo \
      --max-procs=$cores  \
      --replace \
      --verbose \
      /bin/sh -c "{}"
```

Comment: Thanks! This method is better than all other answers. Setting the processes manually often leads to either under-performance or throttling.

Answer (score 42):

Use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It's an incredibly powerful tool  and official packages exist for about 20 or so linux distros. What's that? [You have an excuse as to why you *can't* use it?](http://oletange.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html) Here's a simple example showing how to run a list or file of commands in parallel:

Contents of `jobs.txt`:

```
sleep 1; echo "a"
sleep 3; echo "b"
sleep 2; echo "c"
```

Command:

```
time parallel :::: jobs.txt
```

Results:

```
a
c
b

real    0m3.332s
user    0m0.170s
sys     0m0.037s
```

---

Notes:

If you wish to keep the order the same as the input, pass the `-k` flag to GNU parallel.

If you have more than eight cores and only wish to process with eight cores, add `-j 8` to the args list.

The [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) is a good read, but if you haven't already read [this tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) I would highly recommend the time investment.

Comment: GNU parallel isn't available on Ubuntu 11.10, but it's available on Debian sid. It's also worth noting that this example will *not* work as-is with the parallel utility from the moreutils package, which has some different semantics.

Comment: -j 8 is not needed - it is automatically detected. Ubuntu package: https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries?package=parallel&project=home%3Atange&repository=xUbuntu_11.10

Comment: In order to run commands from a file in parallel you could do `cat /path/to/file.txt | parallel`

Answer (score 0):

You can start new processes on the background simply by running a command with &. There is an example [here](http://pebblesinthesand.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/a-srcipt-for-running-processes-in-parallel-in-bash/) describing a solution of your problem.