# Parallel execution of a job which takes multiple inputs on Linux

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have a file with a list of paths. e.g.:

> /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/CNMC_N_191/
>   /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/204-196/

I have a program (let's call it 'prog') which takes 3 parameters, 2 input filenames and 1 output filename. Normal execution:

```
prog ~/A.txt ~/B.txt ~/out.txt
```

I want to execute in parallel my program with parameters constructed based on each line of the file, e.g.:

```
prog /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/CNMC_N_191/A.txt /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/CNMC_N_191/B.txt /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/CNMC_N_191/out.txt
prog /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/204-196/A.txt /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/204-196/B.txt /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/8_mo/204-196/out.txt
```

I have been trying to use xargs and GNU parallel, but I can't construct a proper command line for those tools. Here is my attempt:

```
cat ListPaths.txt | xargs -I '{}' -n 1 -P 8 ./SkullSegmenter/SkullSegmenter '{}'A.txt '{}'B.txt '{}'out.txt
```

But this does not construct the arguments properly. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I reformatted my list into full commands, and used answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488184/how-can-i-run-a-list-of-commands-in-parallel

Comment: This didn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
cat ListPaths.txt | parallel ./SkullSegmenter/SkullSegmenter {}A.txt {}B.txt {}out.txt
```

Test with `--dry-run` to see if these are the commands you want run:

```
cat ListPaths.txt | parallel --dry-run ./SkullSegmenter/SkullSegmenter {}A.txt {}B.txt {}out.txt
```

Comment: I run: `cat ListPaths.txt | parallel -j 8 ./SkullSegmenter/SkullSegmenter {}SubjectBoneWithoutSuturesIndividualV2.nrrd {}RegisteredSegmentedTemplateV2.nrrd {}SegmentedSubjectV2.nrrd`

I get:
`SubjectBoneWithoutSuturesIndividualV2.nrrd7/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/18_mo/CNMC_N_118/

Exception
Line: 143
SubjectBoneWithoutSuturesIndividualV2.nrrdor reading file /run/user/1007/gvfs/smb-share:server=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/18_mo/CNMC_N_118/
The file doesn't exist.
SubjectBoneWithoutSuturesIndividualV2.nrrderver=xeonator,share=c/Results/Normals/18_mo/CNMC_N_118/`

Comment: It looks like only the path from the file is passed as an argument, and it is not merged with file names A, B and out.

Comment: Since I do not use SkullSegmenter, can you re-test with the command `echo` and maybe use some short input, so it is not so hard to decipher? Also: what did the `--dry-run` give?

Comment: I tried it again, this time it is working - the paths are passed correctly. Meanwhile I got sudo priviledge so I could mount that share in a more sane location (`~/y`). Passing paths starting with `~/y/` did not work (file not found), but writing full paths (`/home/dzenan/y/`) did. Does running this stuff through SSH make a difference? Anyway, thanks for help @Ole Tange

Comment: GNU Parallel quotes the input, so if the input is `~/y` then GNU Parallel treats this as `~/y` and not `your_homedir/y`. You may be able to force the shell to dequote it by prepending the command to run with `eval`.